# Search for a string and delete till occurrence of next character

Tags: sed

String 1: `svn+ssh://test@svn-server.com/repo-2015/branches/DEV_BRANCH_21/main/code/main_input.c`

Needs output: `main/code/main_input.c`

String 2: `svn+ssh://test@svn-server.com/repo-2015/branches/TEST_BRANCH_56/main/code/main_output.c`

Needs output: `main/code/main_output.c`

**Tried like this**

```
echo "svn+ssh://test@svn-server.com/repo 2015/branches/DEV_BRANCH_21/main/code/main_input.c" | sed -e 's/^.*\(branches\/\)//g'
```

Don't know how to proceed and remove upto next "/" after branches.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ echo "svn+ssh://test@svn-server.com/repo 2015/branches/DEV_BRANCH_21/main/code/main_input.c" | grep -oP 'branches/.*?/\K.*'
main/code/main_input.c

$ echo "svn+ssh://test@svn-server.com/repo-2015/branches/TEST_BRANCH_56/main/code/main_output.c" | grep -oP 'branches/.*?/\K.*'
main/code/main_output.c
```

- `branches/.*?/\K` means string matching `branches` followed by `/` and then text upto next `/` . See [perldoc - Lookaround documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns) for further reading

With `sed`

```
sed 's|.*branches/[^/]*/||'
```

- `[^/]*` will match text other than `/`

Answer (score 2):

Using POSIX shell pattern stripping operators:

```
string=svn+ssh://srv.com/repo/branches/TEST_BRANCH_56/main/code/main_output.c
output=${string#*/branches/*/}
```

That will strip the smallest leading part of `$string` that matches that pattern. It's different from:

```
printf '%s\n' "$string" | sed '
  :1
  $!{
   N;b1
  }
  s|.*/branches/[^/]*/||'
```

Or:

```
expr " $string" : ' .*/branches/[^/]*/\(.*\)'
```

in cases like `string=foo/branches/bar/branches/baz/whatever` where the `${string#pattern}` one would return `branches/baz/whatever` while the other ones would return just `whatever`.

Answer (score 1):

I would use grep like this:

```
echo "svn+ssh://test@svn-server.com/repo 2015/branches/DEV_BRANCH_21/main/code/main_input.c" | grep -Eo "main\/code.*"
```

Comment: Thanks but the folder after the branch may be different like svn+ssh://test@svn-server.com/repo 2015/branches/DEV_BRANCH_21/support/feature1/main_input.c. I want to get the string after the branch name(branch name also changes (: )

Comment: Ok, now I get what you were trying to do. Maybe you should explain this better in the question.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed`, similar to what you already did:

```
$ echo "svn+ssh://srv.com/repo/branches/TEST_BRANCH_56/main/code/main_output.c" | 
  sed -e 's,^.*branches/[^/]*/,,g'
main/code/main_output.c
```

After "`branches/`", match any number (`*`) of anything but slashes (`[^/]`), and another slash. The capture group isn't needed here, and I changed the delimiter on the `s` command to a comma so there's no need to escape all the slashes.

Answer (score 0):

Simple way with `awk`  without use of regular expressions:

```
$ awk '{print substr($0,match($0,/main/));}' input.txt                                                                   
main/code/main_input.c
main/code/main_output.c
```